# How to copy text from vim to external application without using mouse?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim, mouse

I am trying to avoid usage of mouse by using keyboard only
so that I can speed up things. Also, I am not great in VIM.
My only motivation to vim is that everything should be possible
through keyboard and therefore I can do things faster.

What I did?

```
#vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

1) Took the cursor to a desired line.
Next, I pressed - `shift + v`

and it says it is now in the `VISUAL LINE`

2) Next, I pressed the arrow key down to select the 
bunch of lines.

3) `Pressed y`

it says - `" 22 lines yanked"`
I believe that means it has copied 22 lines which I selected.

4) I went to gedit and tried doing `ctrl + shift + v`
but it didn't work. Next, I tried doing `ctrl+ v` that also
didn't work. What is the usual way to do so?

Comment: [How can I copy text to the system clipboard from Vim? - Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim) has a **very extensive answer**.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have vim compiled with clipboard for this to work. You can check if your Vim has this by using :echo has('clipboard') from within Vim (if the output is 0, it's not present, if it's 1, it is).

[This answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-can-i-copy-text-to-the-system-clipboard-from-vim) has some more info on the topic

If you do, the following in your .vimrc would do the job:

```
" paste from system CTRL-C clipboard
nnoremap <Leader>p "+p
" paste from system highlghted clipboard (linux only)
nnoremap <Leader>P "*p
" copy contents of unnamed register to system CTRL-C clipboard
nnoremap <silent><Leader>y :call Preserve("normal! Gp\"+dGu")<cr>
            \ :echo 'copied to CTRL-C clipboard'<cr>
" copy contents of unnamed register to system highlghted clipboard (linux only)
nnoremap <silent><Leader>Y :call Preserve("normal! Gp\"*dGu")<cr>
            \ :echo 'copied to highlight clipboard'<cr>

function! Preserve(command)
    " Preparation: save last search, and cursor position.
    let _s=@/
    let l = line(".")
    let c = col(".")
    " Do the business:
    execute a:command
    " Clean up: restore previous search history, and cursor position
    let @/=_s
    call cursor(l, c)
endfunction
```

So with the text yanked, you would press your <leader>y and then you could go to some other application and do ctrl+v and it would paste.

The <leader> key is the backslash by default, so you'd do '\+y'.

In the case that you want to paste text copied from an external application into vim, you can either do ctrl+shift+v, or with the above mapping, p

If you want to avoid the mouse while browsing, [Vimium](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=Vimium) is a great extension that lets you browse using vim-like keys.